# Defining Flex 4 Skins with CSS

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, skinning

I am trying to define my Flex 4 Skins via CSS but I my custom skin will not display. Here is what I am doing:

In my application I import my css and define the styleName in my button:

```
        <fx:Style source="styles.css"/>
        <s:Button label="Button" styleName="circle"/>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
@namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
@namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";

s|Button.circle
{
    skinClass: ClassReference("skins.buttons.CircleButton");
}
```

My understanding is that my button should be supplied it's skinClass via the CSS but it fails to work. If I define the skinClass directly like below it works fine:

```
<s:Button label="Button" skinClass="skins.buttons.CircleButton"/>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you declare Style tag in the main Application file?

Comment: I was defining it within a view, I just moved it into the main application file and now it works fine with the type selector.Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have your CSS file under the root Application file first.  Second, I would try to do the css without the type selector, so instead of `s|Button.circle`, just do `.circle`.

EDIT

You can also try putting the style in a Style tag within the same container as your button to see if that works.  Are you sure your application can find your style.css?  Showing more code might help the situation.

Comment: Thanks! I removed the type selector as you suggested and it worked. I was following an adobe TV tutorial (http://tv.adobe.com/watch/adc-presents/migrating-to-flex-4-using-skins/) which uses it so I guessed it would work, how would I ensure one skin is used across all buttons?

Comment: You can use the type selector then `s|Button{...}`.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [official Flex CSS documentation](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/CSS+Advanced+Selectors):

> Class Selector: A CSS class selector
>   matches components that meet a class
>   condition. The CSS syntax to declare a
>   class selector is to prefix the
>   condition with a dot. You can either
>   declare a class selector as a
>   condition of a type selector, or
>   universally to any type that meets the
>   class condition.

```
.header { background-color: #CCCCCC; }

HBox.footer { background-color: #999999; }
```

> Note: In Flex a class condition is met
>   using the styleName attribute on a
>   component. For example, you may have
>   two classes of HBox: "header" and
>   "footer". Above, the first selector
>   applies to any component with
>   styleName="header"; the second
>   selector should only apply to HBox
>   components with styleName="footer"
>   (something that actually needs to be
>   fixed and enforced in Gumbo, as
>   to-date class selectors have only been
>   universal and any type in the selector
>   is ignored).

It looks like selectors may not be working in Gumbo...

Comment: It isn't called 'Gumbo' anymore since its release last year and your example were of Flex 3.

Comment: Can you get class selectors to work at all? I haven't worked with them before. Gumbo is still the codename for Flex 4/4.1.  Hero is the codename for 4.5.  These names don't just vanish upon release.

Comment: Codenames are used for products that don't have a finalized name or version yet.  You don't hear anyone calling Windows 7 by it's codename Longhorn do you?  It's Flex 4 now.  Flex 4.5 is codenamed Hero because it hasn't been finalized yet.

Comment: I never called Windows 7 by Longhorn as that was the codename for Windows Vista.  The fact still stands, when someone says (or documentation refers to) Gumbo, it will always mean Flex 4. When someone says Hero, it will always mean Flex 4.5.